# Is there an alternative to Class.isAssignableFrom that works with Type objects?

Tags: java, reflection

In Java, [`Class`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) has an [`isAssignableFrom` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29) defined as follows:

> ```
> public boolean isAssignableFrom(Class<?> cls)
> ```
>
> Determines if the class or interface represented by this `Class` object is either the same as, or is a superclass or superinterface of, the class or interface represented by the specified `Class` parameter. It returns `true` if so; otherwise it returns `false`. If this `Class` object represents a primitive type, this method returns `true` if the specified `Class` parameter is exactly this `Class` object; otherwise it returns `false`.
>
> Specifically, this method tests whether the type represented by the specified `Class` parameter can be converted to the type represented by this `Class` object via an identity conversion or via a widening reference conversion. See The Java Language Specification, sections 5.1.1 and 5.1.4 , for details.
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> `cls` - the `Class` object to be checked
>
> #### Returns:
>
> the `boolean` value indicating whether objects of the type `cls` can be assigned to objects of this class

`Class` implements the `Type` interface. Is there an equivalent `isAssignableFrom` method that works on `Type`s instead of just `Class`es? For example, is there a method that determines if a variable of type `List<String>` (which would be represented via an instance of [`ParameterizedType`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html)) can be assigned to a variable of type `List<? extends Object>`?

Comment: you probably can dig around frameworks like guice/cdi/spring that must handle type algorithms internally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [javaRuntype](http://javaruntype.com) -- I've found it useful. It can produce representations of types from instances of `java.lang.reflect.Type`, and test assignability between them.

Comment: can it decide that `List<String>` is a subtype of `List<?>`?

Comment: Yes, given a `org.javaruntype.type.Type` `s` representing `List<String>` and a `org.javaruntype.type.Type` `t` representing `List<?>`, it answers `true` to `t.isAssignableFrom(s)`.

Answer (score 2):

Guava's [TypeToken](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReflectionExplained) utility provides that functionality. Your query could be answered like this:

```
// represents List<String>
ParameterizedType stringList = ...; 

// represents List<? extends Object>
TypeToken objectList = new TypeToken<List<? extends Object>>(){};

boolean isAssignable = objectList.isAssignableFrom( stringList );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast between any List<...>-s, the protection is weaker than normally.

Try this

```
    List<String> a = new Vector<String>();
    List<Integer> b = new Vector<Integer>();
    Integer i = new Integer(0);

    b.add(2);

    a = (List<String>) (Object) b;

    System.out.println((Object)a.get(0));
```

no exceptions will be thrown.

This is because generics are only compile time notion.

If you write

```
           System.out.println(a.get(0));
```

you will get ClassCastException because println function version determined at compile time will be println(String arg).

Ah, so the answer to the question: it should be incorrect to have such an alternative.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. I have two `Type` objects and I want to know if a hypothetical variable of the first `Type` could theoretically be assigned a value from another hypothetical variable of the second `Type`. I am already aware of type erasure. Thank you, though. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is `TypeUtils.isAssignable(Type, Type)` in Apache Commons Lang3